# AlertDialog lost when new Activity begins

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog appear whenever I find that the device location has changed. This happens pretty much at anytime the application sees fit.

The problem is that if the dialog appears just before a new Activity is started the dialog disappears with the old Activity. Is there anyway to have the AlertDialog block new Intents? Or translate over to the new Activity (could I update the Context)?

I noticed that AlertDialogs don't even handle the case where the device rotates, so my hope for this isn't too high, but any input would help.

Comment: You're right, Alert Dialogs cannot handle this, but Toasts do, so if you are not to pressured about using an AlertDialog, you could use a Toast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use a SharedPreference setting and check it whenever your potentially interruptive Activity starts.

Ex;

1. set shared preference value to 1
2. start dialogue
3. when finished, save the shared preference to 0
4. if activity starts and shared preference is 1, it interrupted so start an alert dialogue. if it is 0, move on.

Again, an AlertDialog is meant to attach itself to an activity, so you really can't stop it from dieing, if your previous activity is pushed back or loses focus of the screen (ui thread basically put on hold!)

Hope you can fix your problem with this minor fixup.

To add what Daniel commented, Custom toasts *can* be awesome. They are, however, limited to about 3.5 seconds (I think)
More on Custom Toasts; http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView

Comment: I definitely believe a custom Toast would get it done. And there are hacks that allow you to show a Toast for longer than 3.5 seconds.

Comment: In the end I chose to change my design so that Activities check to see if a Dialog should be shown rather than trying to create a global dialog. I think this fits with the design of the Android framework.

Comment: I'm glad you found a "Correct" solution to your problem -- it's sometimes hard to see it in Android, but its always nice to see it happen :)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear for me,As I understood you need to show a Alertdialog whenever the device location is changed that too above a new activity.My suggestion is that when ever the device location changes get the need values,bundle it with the intent and pass it starting a new activity.With the bundle also pass a boolean flag.If the boolean flag is true in the new activity show a Alertdialog box in `onCreate`,I hope you will get what you wanted.This will be the best scenario for you to do this as I understood.Also keeping the history of these activity's may affect the app while implementing this.

Comment: There isn't one Activity that handles the location stuff. Basically I have a settings Activity that the user can choose 'Auto' for their location setting. When this occurs, a Location Manager begins listening for location. The Location Manager has a Context that gets updated every time an Activity begins. When the Manager finds a location, it uses that Context to show an AlertDialog. This can happen at any time. So if the application is about to change Activities, the Dialog will appear on Activity A and then is destroyed(alongside Activity A) when Activity B starts.